# CSS - Vertically center 3 elements

Tags: css

I have a table with 4 columns. At a certain browser width, the last 3 columns are stacked vertically by setting the display value to block. Now, I would like to vertically center these 3 cells in the row, but I have no clue how to do this. Changing the HTML is not an option, so the solution needs to be CSS only.

```css
.myTable tr > td:not(:first-of-type),
.myTable tr > th:not(:first-of-type) {
      display: block;
}
```

```html
     <table class="myTable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>t2</th>
              <th>t3</th>
              <th>t4</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec interdum risus sed libero hendrerit ullamcorper. Aliquam sit amet ante risus. Phasellus interdum consequat diam, at mattis nulla aliquam quis. Ut ac fermentum justo, cursus dapibus augue. Vivamus efficitur ipsum lacus, id semper ex lobortis sollicitudin. Donec luctus, nibh at elementum venenatis, massa justo fermentum enim, et consequat velit diam ut mauris. Duis at dictum turpis.</td>
              <td>Content</td>
              <td>Content</td>
              <td>Content</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efkn6q21/6/)

Currently it looks like this:
[image: Current situation]

But it should be like this:

[image]

Comment: The expected result is for the 3 td elements to be vertically centered in their row.

Comment: You shouldn't be using tables to achieve this layout, which can be easily done using CSS grid or flexbox. Are you at liberty to change the markup?

Comment: @Terry That's what I told the guys who made it like this. Changing the markup at this point would have an impact on the functionality, which I would like to avoid having to fix.

Comment: Well, if you don't change the markup then you'll end up with really ugly hacks to get it to work, since a table element is not supposed to be used as such. Sometimes you've got to put your foot down and simply put a stop to markup abuse, otherwise there's really not much we can do since it's an unintended use case ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯